# How to list all recoverable deleted files and folders?

Tags: linux, filesystems, security, data-recovery, ext4

Is there a way to **list** all deleted files and folders which can be recovered in Linux? Is there a way to show the health of recoverability of those deleted files and folders?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the rm command, then the only way to see what files are available to recover is to recover them. I do not know any such tools for Linux, sorry.
If you used the GUI, just look in the folder filled with deleted items.